# Why was 'Avoiding jQueryUI' deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155156/avoiding-jqueryui  and then went to vote it up to find it had been deleted.. I didn't get to read the whole thing but from my skimming of it it seemed to be a perfectly valid question. Can someone tell me why this post was deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author deleted it. Presumably for reasons of his own. Or *possibly* as a result of subliminal mind-control from invading space creatures. You might want to crack open the heads of those around you and feast on the goo inside, *just to be safe*...

Comment: Safety is important. Safety is important. Safety is important.